# How to Escape OR Ignore some part of a String in php?

Tags: php, string, parsing, escaping

Consider I Have a String like `$str = "input(<here some dynamic content>)"`

> Note:- input(<here some dynamic content>) this is a whole string not a Function or Something like that.

I want to escape or ignore content which is in between `input(.........)` string.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Please stop spamming unrelated tags - thank you!

Comment: Ehm, does something like `$str = preg_replace('/^input\(.*\)$/', 'input()', 'input(.....)');` solve this?

Comment: Hey @Jared I don't want to replace I want to escape that part which is in between `input()` string

Comment: Use [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback)

Comment: Please show an example of actual input and desired results.

Comment: hey, @Barmar `$str = "input('Lorem Ipsum')"` is consider as input and output should be `$str = "input()"` but Content which is Lorem Ipsum should not be removed It just be Ignored or escaped

Comment: Add clarifications to the question, not comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored"? Your sample output has it removed.

Comment: Ignored... by what? what for? What this `input(...)` string is for?

Comment: "escape" - for HTML, for shell, for SQL, for regex, or for a MS DOS batch file, or what? Now, re: _Consider I Have a String like $str = "input(<here some dynamic content>)"_ -- how about, consider that you could simply have `$input = 'Here some dynamic content'` instead. Why should it end up inside `input(...)` to begin with, only to be ignored or escaped or whatever, after being separated from it again. **Ignoring it is super easy though. Just define `$str_to_output = 'input()'` and forget that dynamic content ever existed. _You may need to rethink what you're trying to do here._